# Is celery recommended for email sending only?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, celery

I have an api with django rest framework.

The api is for user signup. After signup api will send verification email to the user but sending email takes a little time so for this purpose i want to send email in background.

For this requirement what should be the approach ?

Comment: Yeah go ahead with celery...

Answer (score 2):

This should be your approach to achieve the task which you want to execute.

1. Install celery
2. create a celery.py file in your project folder, where your settings.py file is located(recommended but not necessary)
   and paste the following code into your file.
   Replace example with your project name

```
from celery import Celery
import os
from django.conf import settings

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'example.settings')

app = Celery('example')

app.config_from_object(settings, namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

3. Add these lines in your settings:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://{}:{}'.format(REDIS_SERVER_HOST, REDIS_SERVER_PORT)
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://{}:{}'.format(REDIS_SERVER_HOST, REDIS_SERVER_PORT)
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
```

Make sure to start the Redis server and assign values to REDIS_SERVER_HOST and REDIS_SERVER_PORT variables with appropriate values.

4. Open init.py file of your project directory and paste this code

```
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ['celery_app']
```

5. create a task.py file in your app directory and write a function that sends an email
   For ex:

```
from example import celery_app
from django.core.mail import send_mail

@celery_app.task
def send_celery_email(self, recipient_list):
    # your actual mail function
    send_mail("subject", "message", from_email = 'test@gmail.com', recipient_list = [recipient_list])
```

6. Start your celery server using

```
celery -A project worker --loglevel=info
```

7. call this_function from the views as a normal function and pass the required arguments.

```
from .task import send_celery_email

send_celery_email.delay(recipient_list = [])
```

Note: This is just a roadmap of the workflow, actual code may vary according to your requirements and version of celery.
Also checkout the [documentation](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html)